# Jquery autocomplete doesn't show result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My code:

```
$("#town").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'GET', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                type : "towns", 
                mode: "titles", 
                limit: 20,
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                response(data);
            },
        });
    },
```

Data is Json object. I get it from php after json_encode(array). If I write some letters, I'll have json array with values, but tooltip is not displayed. What is wrong? jquery 1.11.3, jquery-ui 1.11.4
console.log(data) return:

```
Object {query: "Mi", suggestions: Array(4)}
query: "Mi"
suggestions : Array(4)
0 :"Minsk"
1: "Mir"
2:"Mikhailovo"
3:"Miroslavl"
```

and etc.

**UPD**

```
$("#town").autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
```

doesn't work too. Jquery and jquery ui are included. Concole is clear.

Comment: So, where is the url? Could you please show the action that is called?

Comment: It's my local url. It works great. I don't think problem in php, because console.log show right data.

Comment: Does console.log show something? You are not giving enough informations. If the log does not work, the problem is in the url method.

Comment: added console output

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supplying the data in the correct format which the autocomplete expects. You can't just supply any old data and expect it to understand - the response data has to match one of the formats accepted by the plugin.

As per the documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source :

> There are two supported formats:
>
> An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
>
> An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

You need to amend your server-side code to supply the data in one of the allowed formats, or (less efficiently) you can refactor it client-side inside the "success" function before you call the "response" callback.

Comment: I changed success function: `data = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];response(data)` like exemple in docs, but it didn't helped

Comment: any errors in your console? Do you definitely have an textbox with the id "town", which is declared _before_ you run the autocomplete command (or: the autocomplete command is within a "document.ready" block)? It might help if you show us more of your code.

Comment: All Conditions fulfilled. I think problem in versions. I have jquery 1.11.3 and ui 1.11.4 and using them throught cdn. Then I downloaded ui 1.11.4.zip from official site, I found out, that they use jquery 10.6 in it.

Comment: there's no such thing as jQuery 10.6. The newest version is 3.2.1 As per http://jqueryui.com/download/ you only require jQuery 1.7 or above for jQueryUI 1.12.x, or jQuery 1.6 _or above_ for jQueryUI 1.11.x). So if you have jQuery 1.11, you should be fine - later versions are supported. If there was a real version problem, you'd almost certainly have a console error or warning.

Comment: Here's your simplified example, working, with jQuery 1.9: https://jsfiddle.net/oeLb0j0v/1/ (note I used the onDomReady setting for the script in JSFiddle, which is equivalent to wrapping the JS in a document.ready() function). I can't see the rest of your code, so please consider whether you've actually implemented it all correctly.